# FastAPI's jsonanble_encoder raises ValueError when consuming dict from other endpoint

Tags: python, json, encoding, fastapi

I have a very simple FastAPI app. Directly calling endpoint `"b/{id}"`, correctly returns the JSON object. However, calling endpoint endpoint `"a/{id}"`—which returns the response of method `b(id)`—results in the following error:

```
jsonable_encoder raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Here is my sample code

```py
@app.post("/a/{id}", response_class=JSONResponse)
def a(id):
    return b(id)


@app.get("/b/{id}", response_class=JSONResponse)
def b(id):
    return {"id":id}
```

Somehow the `jsonable_encoder` is having problems but I don't know why.

Comment: Either `await` the call to  `b`, or probably better: move the common part out to a function that you re-use in both locations, either as a dependency (with FastAPI `Depends()` or as a plain Python function).